# How to implement a ListView in a Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

I have `Fragment.java` and its XML. In XML I put `ListView` and I want to update the `ListView` in `Fragment` and add some `String`.
I am trying to make a custom adapter. When I run the `ListView` in `Activity` with custom adapter all works great, but when I put the same code in `Fragment` nothing happens. I am using EventBus3.

This is my Activity send Event

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new SendDataHelper(nameOfItem[myItemInt]));
```

This is my Fragment:

```
public class MyOrderFragment extends Fragment {
TextView name;
ListView listOrder;
private Context context;
List<cources> collegeList;

public MyOrderFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);


}
@Subscribe
public void onMessageEvent(SendDataHelper event){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String text = event.getText();
    name.setText(text);
    cources college;
    collegeList = new ArrayList<cources>();
    college = new cources();
    college.name = "sharon";
    collegeList.add(college);
    listOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(collegeList, context);
    listOrder.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_order_fragment, container, false);
    name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    listOrder = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listOrder);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

This is my adapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Context context;
List<cources> valueList;

public ListAdapter(List<cources> listValue, Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.valueList = listValue;
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return this.valueList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return this.valueList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewItem viewItem = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        viewItem = new ViewItem();
        LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_view, null);

        viewItem.txtNamePlanche = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tx_name_planche);
        viewItem.txtPriceBaget = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tx_price_baget);
        viewItem.txtPricePlate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tx_price_plate);
        convertView.setTag(viewItem);
    }
    else
    {
        viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewItem.txtNamePlanche.setText(valueList.get(position).name);
    viewItem.txtPriceBaget.setText(valueList.get(position).price_baget);
    viewItem.txtPricePlate.setText(valueList.get(position).price_plate);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

This is my ItemView

```
import android.widget.TextView;

class ViewItem
{
TextView txtNamePlanche;
TextView txtPricePlate;
TextView txtPriceBaget;
}
```

This is cources:

```
public class cources
{
public String name;
public String price_plate;
public String price_baget;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Or is the listView just not populating anything?

Comment: Nothings happens
no errors

Comment: Can you please post the full code?  I have a few questions but it would be easier to just see

Comment: Look i will add code to other my answer

Comment: You should edit your question add put your code in there

Comment: Fixed grammar and improved formatting. The code still requires editing, please post the whole code, not only parts of it. Thank you.

Comment: Look i add all my codes to main post
now if i make the ListView visble but i am not use the adapter then the app not crash.
so i need find way to put the item to list without this adapter i think that i need other adapter but i am not sure how to make one for fragment because my adapter is for Activity

Answer (score 0):

Change extends Fragment to extends ListFragment

Comment: I tried it before, But the fragment give me error in OnCreateView and if delete this class the app will crash.
It's because i am using Material Design with Tabs and when MainActivity create tab and his fragment he do it like this:
        MainActivity.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new MainActivity.ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new MainFragment(),         getResources().getString(R.string.Main));